# Show Specific Cells if multiple dropdowns equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

is it possible to have Excel show all data from specific columns and rows by way of a Vlookup up or index match using multiple dropdowns to give the required search variables.

E.g.:

- Drop down 1 has London selected,
- Dropdown 2 has telephone selected,
- Dropdown 3 has internal selected and
- Dropdown 4 has PM selected.

The formula will then search worksheet 2 that has the data set in columns and return the result of the entire matching column into a cell on worksheet 1.

Hope that makes sense but if you need any more details please ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following in Excel (not using VBA) for when there is a **unique match**. You create a key that joins all the ID fields at the start of the table. I used a spacer "-" to make it easy to read the parts.

So if your Data Table looks like this:

**Key / City / Contact / Internal / AM or PM / Other data fields**

So in Column A of your data block you have a constructed key:

```
= City & "-" & Contact & "-" & Internal & "-" & AM
```

i.e. so in A2 its:

```
= B2 & "-" & C2 &  "-" & D2 & "-" & E2
```

I then create this key from the dropdowns and look this up.

So your dropdowns are looking up key string

"London-Telephone-Internal-PM"

As your dropdowns change your key changes and then you are using this 4 in 1 key to find your data in your `VLOOKUP`.

Cheesy but easy. Others may have smarter methods.

**EDIT MINI EXAMPLE USING TWO IDs**

*My Data Table*

```
Col A / B / C / D
ID / City / Telephone / Other

"London-Tele" / London / Tele / Likes fish and chips
"London-Mobile" / London / Mobile / Dont call before 9am
"Tokyo-Mobile" / Tokyo / Mobile / Likes sushi
...
```

Note first column ID is created as a formula here in A2 you have B2&"-"&C2

*my lookup*

I get user selection from my drop down boxes. 
Dropdowns feed me "London-Tele" into cell call it `rngSelection`. This cell is getting the answer from Dropdown 1 and then Answer Dropdown 2 and then ans1&"-"&ans2 to make the key.

In my other sheet I have to get the Other data in column D

```
= VLOOKUP(rngSelection, rngDataTable, 4, FALSE)
```

which will return in this cell the answer

Likes fish and chips

P.S. I like to do this to error trap

```
= IF( ISERROR(VLOOKUP(rngSelection, rngDataTable, 4, FALSE)),"Not found",
 VLOOKUP(rngSelection, rngDataTable, 4, FALSE)
```

Comment: Ok so i understood up to the point of adding the string to the dropdowns.

Comment: @James Mook I added a mini example with two ID fields. Your drop downs give you two answers , you glue them together to get a key, this key is a simple formula in first column of your data table. Your VLOOKUP uses this double key to get the value out of the table.

Comment: You can either have your four Dropdowns operating independently (but you risk getting some mismatches/not founds but easier for user to operate). Or create your index 4 in 1 column in your data table and have one unique Dropdown using this Frankenstein index. This depends on your users.

Comment: Perfect i understand better now. Is there any way for this method to display a certain selection of cells i.e if the result produced is 'fish' it will then show the the values of say cells E1:E5? Thanks for all your help

Comment: Bit confused here. How are cells E1:E5 related to fish? Is it information in your Data Table? If is it in your data table then you can have multiple VLOOKUPs and then use different offsets (i.e. replace 4 with 5) if you have another column in data table next to Other to pull out the data. Have you used VLOOKUPs before?

Comment: the idea was that when it found the cell with say 'fish' in it then it would then display the results found in E1:E5 as an example. The reason being is that there are a few telephone numbers that i would need to display as the end result so that the user can then pick a telephone number to try. Hope that makes more sense? If it can't be done i'll have to try entering all the numbers within 1 cell and see if it formats ok.

Comment: I have figured this out now and can get it to do what i want by way of an array formula. I just need to put my brain in gear to put your formula together with the array. Thanks for your help.